# Cron job running at 12.00 AM despite changing its time

Tags: centos, cron, cpanel

I have only one cron configured in cPanel for WHMCS to run once per day at 12.00 AM.

The cron sends daily activity logs to my email.

A problem came up recently in which cron job activity logs sent to me from that email *`noreply@yourdomain.com`* which does not exist. Emails are coming from that address without replacing my actual domain name.

So I deleted the cron job, I created a new one with different timing 8.00 AM. The cron runs correctly at that time and I'm receiving logs from my valid email. However, I still get emails at 12.00 AM too, as If there is another cron job stuck at that time and the logs are coming from that invalid email address *`noreply@yourdomain.com`*.

I looked into the cron configuration file and there were no duplicate entries for crons.
I checked with WHMCS support and the software configuration is correct.

Have anyone had a problem like this before? Any suggestions please? Thank you.

Comment: I don't know "cPanel for WHMCS". Do you have shell access to the system or can you access the whole filesystem somehow? `cron` jobs can be configured in several places: `/etc/crontab`, the files in `/etc/cron.d` and the user files in `/var/spool/cron`. Check them all.

Comment: are mail from noreply@yourdomain.com bounce mail ? (e.g. "mail couldn't be delivered to recipient" style ) if yes, those should go away in time.